# saved blender file doesn't play any audio or video

Tags: video-sequence-editor

[image]As the title says. I have rendered this file before and saved it. But now when I open the blender file, the strips are all in the same locations but when I try to render or play video in VSE it shows with nothing. What is weird is, if I import a new audio or video it will play.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED all I had to do is move my blender file back to where I saved it. I recently moved the file to another folder and just by moving it back to the original folder it worked.